# 160V capacitor for smoothing

Tags: power-supply, power

Will a 2200uf 160v capacitor be ok to smooth a 110v dc supply.
240 to 110 transformer to a bridge rectifier to load.
will it give me 110 volts or 160 volts output? 
Many Thanks

Comment: 1nF is enough but it depends on the load and how much ripple voltage you can tolerate.

Comment: Add 50Hz input and 500mA avg to question with minimum load and peak load then tolerance to Vdc mean and ripple. Also include transformer V ratio and rate VA output and allow no load Vdc to rise 50% above full load Vac rms output (41% +9% loss)

Answer (score 6):

The DC output of a bridge rectifier is √2 times the rms AC input, minus the diode drops.  So for 110V in, you get 155V out.  The capacitor needs to have a voltage rating larger than the voltage it's exposed to. 160V is larger than 155V, but it's cutting it close, especially as the ripple current in rectifiers is hard on capacitors.  So I would suggest a higher rated one - for a long term reliable circuit, I'd go for double the output voltage, so 320V.

Answer (score 3):

160V is not enough margin for this application. The nominal peak voltage coming out of your rectifier is 155V, and if your line voltage goes 10% high, you'll exceed the rating of the capacitor. Use at least a 200V unit.

Comment: The load is very small probably 500ma

Comment: In that case, assuming 50 Hz line frequency and a full-wave rectifier, the ripple voltage will be about 2.27 Vp-p.

Answer (score 2):

The guys already said, you should have a wider margin, usually at least 25%. I would like to add a little about the capacity. You said, it's 2200uF, it's pretty huge number. Are you sure it's justified?

The way to know that is to look at your load current and power network cycle. The rectifier recharges the capacitor ones per 8msec (120Hz!) or 16msec if you use single diode. Within that time all available energy is stored in the capacitor. If you have a load with relatively constant current, use It=cV equation to estimate, what voltage will your capacitor reach before recharge. Unless you have very high power load, smaller capacitor may be enough.

Answer (score 1):

Where do you live if you have 110VAC at the wall? This is normally 120VAC in North America, so these other answers are underrated even if you add 10%. And to be safe, add at least 20% to the nominal AC voltage. It's not unheard of to measure AC mains voltage at +10%. This means your rectified voltage should be able to handle a 144VAC input, or rectified ~203.65 VDC.